# How can I fix the 'expected 1 argument' error when using Yup's conditional validation in React?

Tags: reactjs, yup

I am trying to use Yup when condition.

```
email: Yup.string()
                .label('Email professionnel')
                .when(['validateEmailExist'], {
                        is: true,
                        then: Yup.string().test('emailexists',
                            'Email déjà utilisé !',
                            async (value) => {
                                if (value) {
                                    try {
                                        let response = await axios.get<boolean>(`/api/resources/existEmail/${companyId}/${value}`);
                                        if (response.data !== true) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    } catch (error) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }),
                        otherwise: Yup.string()
                            .matches(/^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/, 'Le champ "Email professionnel" doit être un email valide.')
                            .required(),
                    }),
```

I am trying to check if emailexist only when validateEmailexist is true, but i got an error 'expected 1 argument'.
could any one helps.

Comment: hmh... tried using a function instead of an array function? Had some issues with array functions in the `yup` `when` and changing to the function fixed it

Comment: @Lith could you please give an example of using a function. thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of `(value) => {` write `function (value) {`. If you using eslint, it might be mad since the function here has no name so just disable that rule here for this line.

Comment: also pretty sure you could ditch the `async` if you did a `return axios.get<boolean>(`/api/resources/existEmail/${companyId}/${value}`)` with `.then` and `.catch` blocks instead.